# What word would you use to describe the most interesting man in the world from the dos equis commercials?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to think of a word that describes a person who's skillful, intelligent, capable, interesting, etc.  Think of the character in the most interesting man in the world commercials. What's one word that would describe him?

Some that I've thought of don't have quite the right tone:

> Champion, Badass, Baller

Is there one word that fits the bill?

Comment: I think the word starts with a K and ends with a Z, and may be as few as three letters long, with an A in the middle. :)

Comment: I would say aristocratic or gentlemanly.

Answer (score 2):

*Übermensch.*

> noun:  a person with great powers and abilities

See *[OneLook](http://onelook.com/?w=ubermensch&ls=a)*, *[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubermensch)*.

Answer (score 0):

As well known as he has become, the term "most interesting man in the world" covers it. But you can break it down a little:

After a little investigating, I think **[man's man](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-is-a-mans-man.htm)** or **manly** makes sense, if you were to look for another term. I remember seeing the Dos Equis man cooking in a apron, while yelling at a tiger to get off of the dinner table. Everything he does, he does in a manly fashion, even if it is not a manly activity. "He wouldn't be afraid to show his feminine side, if he had one."

He is a noted "polymath" or "renaissance man", which is a person whose expertise spans a significant number of different fields. "He received the lifetime achievement award, twice." This begins to capture the grandiose admiration for the type of man.

"Superman" (or Übermensch, which, of course, isn't English) doesn't hint at how culturally sophisticated and fascinating this man is. ("When he goes to a museum, he is allowed to touch the exhibits.")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure any one word really fills the bill perfectly, and context matters tremendously here, so let me throw a few words your way, any one of which might at least come close to what you're looking for when used in particular ways: a star, a killer, a god, a mensch, a king, an ace, the top, the best, a winner.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure that this fits with the rest of the responses, but I suggest “charismatic” as an answer to the question.